# Where to put my code so that it executes after my service starts?

Tags: c#, windows-services

just wondering where to put my code so that it executes after my service starts.

currently i have my code like this

```
    namespace sendMailService
    {
        public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
        {
            public Service1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                this.sendMail();

            }
            protected override void OnStop()
            {
            }
            private void sendMail() 
            {
              // My actual service code
            }
        }

    }
```

When i start the service, it wouldn't get to "Running" mode till the `this.sendMail()` completes. Incidentally, the last line of the `sendMail()` function is to `stop()` the service. So, the service crashes by the time it executes the `OnStart` method.

I know why its happening like this (because the code is in `OnStart`). The question is where to call the `sendMail()` so that the Service gets to running mode and then execute the function.

Comment: Well, you could presumably schedule it to do that on another thread, e.g. with `Task.Run`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate your code as to fix your problem.

```
namespace sendMailService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private System.Threading.Timer IntervalTimer;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            TimeSpan tsInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, Properties.Settings.Default.PollingFreqInSec);
            IntervalTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                new System.Threading.TimerCallback(IntervalTimer_Elapsed)
                , null, tsInterval, tsInterval);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            IntervalTimer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
            IntervalTimer.Dispose();
            IntervalTimer = null;
        }

        private void IntervalTimer_Elapsed(object state)
        {   
             // Do the thing that needs doing every few minutes...
             sendMail();
        }
    }
}
```